# How to set the opacity of a ListView row in android?

Tags: android, listview

I want to set the `opacity` of each and every `Listview row` using `android:alpha`. I tried doing so but the row doesn't get the transparent background. I have a colorful background of the layout and I want a glass or transparent type of row of the ListView. How can I do it?. I don;t want to use any adapters for this. So please suggest some simple methods.

Comment: Have you checked that the ListView itself doesn't have a background color?

Comment: you may wanna set background of list item transparant.

Comment: Yes, I want to set the background of the List Item transparent.

Answer (score 1):

```
View backgroundimage = findViewById(R.id.background);
Drawable background = backgroundimage.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are set opacity of listView us below Code
android:background="#80ColorCode"

Comment: I am getting the glass like background for the whole ListView. I just want that background for the ListView Items/Listview rows. How can i do that?